# Why doesn't my sidebar element with CSS "height: 100%" actually extend to 100%?

Tags: html, css, height, sidebar

I have problem in layout of page in css. I have sidebar that height doesn't 100%. I want to show sidebar in 100%, but I can't. how to increase height of sidebar to 100%. I have `.container-fluid` with `position: relative` and `.sidebar` with `position: relative`.

this is my code:

```css
body {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    height:100%
}
#sidebar {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-color: #222A2D;
}
.container-fluid {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.main {
    margin-left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
    color:red;
    padding-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<body id="mainbody">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header>Header</header>
        
        <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>menu1</li>
                <li>menu2</li>
                <li>menu3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="main" id="main">
            Main content
            <br>
            Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
          
            <br>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the height of the html tag, your .container-fluid and the  sidebar also to 100%.

Basically all parent tags need to been set to 100% to solve your issue. However when there is another element around it won't look so nice.

```css
html { height:100%; }

body {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    height:100%
}
#sidebar {
    height:100%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-color: #222A2D;
}
.container-fluid {
    height:100%
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.main {
    margin-left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
    color:red;
    padding-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<body id="mainbody">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header>Header</header>
        
        <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>menu1</li>
                <li>menu2</li>
                <li>menu3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="main" id="main">
            Main content
            <br>
            Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
          
            <br>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping . but when my content will increase, my sidebar couldn't up to 100%. please see http://jsfiddle.net/qwoy66ep/

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
  <style>
    body {
        background-color: #e8e8e8;
        font-family: 'Open Sans';
        height: 100%;
    }

    #sidebar {
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

    .sidebar {
        width: 220px;
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        background-color: #222A2D;
    }

    .container-fluid {
        height:100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }

    .main {
        margin-left: 0;
        min-height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin-right: 15px;
        color: red;
        padding-left: 250px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I add only two properties in **.container-fluid**
 **height:100%;**
 **position: absolute;**

Comment: Thanks for helping . but when my content will increase, my sidebar couldn't up to 100%. please see http://jsfiddle.net/qwoy66ep/

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Viewport units*

> The viewport units are a new set of units designed for the challenges
>   we face today. One-pagers, full-width grids, typography, and many
>   other things rely on the size of the viewport. Previously, we hacked
>   these challenges using percentages as mentioned earlier, or
>   JavaScript.
>
> This new set of units consists of four different units. Two for each
>   axis, and a minimum and maximum value of the two.
>
> - vw: 1/100th viewport width
> - vh: 1/100th viewport height
> - vmin: 1/100th of the smallest side
> - vmax: 1/100th of the largest side

So 1vh = 1% of screen.

Try this:

```css
body {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    margin: 0;
}
#sidebar {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.sidebar {
    width: 220px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 22px);  /*the height of the screen minus the header's height (right now 22px), if it changes you can change it in calc to make it more accurate*/
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-color: #222A2D;
}
.container-fluid {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.main {
    margin-left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 15px;
    color:red;
    padding-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
        <header>Header</header>
        
        <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>menu1</li>
                <li>menu2</li>
                <li>menu3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="main" id="main">
            Main content
            <br>
            Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
          
            <br>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
```

The use of `height: calc(100vh - 22px)` is just to avoid the unnecessary vertical scroll if you only set `height: 100vh` you will notice it.

Comment: Thanks for helping . but when my content will increase, my sidebar couldn't up to 100%. please see http://jsfiddle.net/qwoy66ep/

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem with change sidebar `position: absolute;` and `left:0;` and use html tag with `position: relative;` and use `min-height:100%;` in any sections.

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
} 

body {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
     min-height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 220px;
     background: #3a3633;    
    min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 904;
    padding-top: 49px;
}

.container-fluid {
    min-height:100%;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.main {
     margin-left: 220px;

   
}
```

```html
<body id="mainbody">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header>Header</header>
        
        <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>menu1</li>
                <li>menu2</li>
                <li>menu3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="main" id="main">
            Main content
            <br>
            Main content
             <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
            <br>Main content
          
            <br>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
</body>
```